# How long should my html be?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am currently developing a website at work, using asp net mvc. And for a page, there is a tab system.

On the same page, three tabs are available, I was wondering if coding the three tabs in the same aspx file, and hide/show them dynamically was the best solution, or if I should create three different aspx page. Because the file is getting heavier every time I am adding a block, for the moment it has around 250 lines.
And I still have a third block to add.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution **at start is to place all the tabs on the page**, and then if you see that the page is slow you can start to make tricks to make it faster. If you do not know, first you make the page, later the optimizations if you really needed them there.

### Some of the tricks.

1. You can make the images to load only when you show each tab. Images adds more delay than text/html.
2. You can make a flush on the first tab, and the page will be shown to the user, then will load the rest, then javascript will run and been able to change tabs.
3. You can load later with iframe and different pages as you say.
4. You can load them later with ajax

What you do at the end is depends from some factors like, **how many users see that page**, how really **big is after the gzip**, and if this is the most delay part of the page or the load of the data from the database

### Real Test

Huge page with **12,000** lines, **gziped 600kb** takes **200 ms** to be send.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your test, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it that place the tabs on your aspx page if you can use jquery ui tabs it will be more manageable . Then identify the tabs with more than normal html move that HTML to  user controls asax file and use them as your tab's content.It will be simple and more manageable.That is a practice mostly used.